# Select unique rows based on condition stored in another table

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query, constraint

I want to select rows based on conditions that is fetched from the database. The tables structure are mentioned below.

```
# Questions Table: 
╔════════════╦═══════════════╦════════╗
║ id         ║ chapter_id    ║ weight ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╬════════╣
║ question-1 ║ first         ║ 1      ║
║ question-2 ║ second        ║ 1      ║
║ question-3 ║ third         ║ 1      ║
║ question-4 ║ first         ║ 2      ║
║ question-5 ║ third         ║ 2      ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╩════════╝
```

```
# Patterns Tables
╔════╦═════════════════╦════════╗
║ id ║ question_number ║ weight ║
╠════╬═════════════════╬════════╣
║ p1 ║ 1               ║ 1      ║
║ p2 ║ 2               ║ 1      ║
║ p3 ║ 3               ║ 1      ║
║ p4 ║ 4               ║ 2      ║
║ p5 ║ 5               ║ 2      ║
╚════╩═════════════════╩════════╝
```

```
# Patterns to SubChapters 
╔════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ pattern_id ║ chapter_id    ║
╠════════════╬═══════════════╣
║ p1         ║ first         ║
║ p2         ║ second        ║
║ p3         ║ third         ║
║ p4         ║ first         ║
║ p4         ║ second        ║
║ p5         ║ second        ║
║ p5         ║ third         ║
╚════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

Now I want to select a unique question for each matching pattern

Required Output:

```
╔════════════╦═════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ pattern_id ║ question_number ║ question_id ║
╠════════════╬═════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ p1         ║ 1               ║ question-1  ║
║ p2         ║ 2               ║ question-2  ║
║ p3         ║ 3               ║ question-3  ║
║ p4         ║ 4               ║ question-4  ║
║ p5         ║ 6               ║ question-5  ║
╚════════════╩═════════════════╩═════════════╝

// p1 can be from first chapter with weight = 1 (i.e. question-1)
// p2 can only be second chapter with weight = 1 (i.e. question-2)
// p3 can be from third chapter with weight = 1 (i.e. question-3)
// p4 can be from first with weight = 2 (question-4)
// p5 can be from third with weight = 2 (question-5)

// similarly if there are multiple options, it should choose randomly from one of them.

// Weight are also considered a condition and the generated question_id column should be unique
```

I am quite new to sql databases still learning, please let me know what can done to tackle this kind of issue? I am using postgres with drizzle orm for my quiz application.

Currently, I have tackled this situation with 100 separate sequential queries, which takes much longer and isn't suitable for running in a cloud function.
[Current Solution](https://github.com/sahrohit/pracharya/blob/cdacae336b8327fc8d7263e9beba55ab44fc9d4b/src/server/api/routers/test.ts#L154C1-L256C6)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a elaborate JOIN, where you combine all three tables.

for the random return you need an CTE to get only one charpter

```
CREATE TABLE Patterns (
  "id" VARCHAR(2),
  "question_number" INTEGER,
  "weight" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Patterns
  ("id", "question_number", "weight")
VALUES
  ('p1', '1', '1'),
  ('p2', '2', '1'),
  ('p3', '3', '1'),
  ('p4', '4', '2'),
  ('p5', '5', '2');

CREATE TABLE Questions (
  "id" VARCHAR(10),
  "chapter_id" VARCHAR(6),
  "weight" INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO Questions
  ("id", "chapter_id", "weight")
VALUES
  ('question-1', 'first', '1'),
  ('question-2', 'second', '1'),
  ('question-3', 'third', '1'),
  ('question-4', 'first', '2'),
  ('question-5', 'third', '2');

CREATE TABLE patterns2subchapter (
  "pattern_id" VARCHAR(2),
  "chapter_id" VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO patterns2subchapter
  ("pattern_id", "chapter_id")
VALUES
  ('p1', 'first'),
  ('p2', 'second'),
  ('p3', 'third'),
  ('p4', 'first'),
  ('p4', 'second'),
  ('p5', 'second'),
  ('p5', 'third');
```

```
wITH CTE AS(
SELECT
p."id" as pattern_id,p."question_number",q."id" as question_id
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p."id" ORDER BY random()) rn
FROM Patterns p LEFT JOIN patterns2subchapter ps ON p."id" = ps."pattern_id"
LEFT JOIN Questions q ON q."chapter_id" = ps."chapter_id" AND q."weight" = p."weight"
WHERE q.id IS NOT NULL)
SELECT pattern_id,"question_number",question_id
FROM CTE WHERE rn = 1
```

| pattern_id | question_number | question_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| p1 | 1 | question-1 |
| p2 | 2 | question-2 |
| p3 | 3 | question-3 |
| p4 | 4 | question-4 |
| p5 | 5 | question-5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/-yoWN6L_)

Comment: This is very close to my required answer, but the only problem i see is the generated question are sometime repeated, is there a way to constrain it as it should only return unique question_id. Thank you so much for the help tho.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `DISTINCT ON`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (pattern_id)
       pattern_id,
       question_id
FROM patterns
   JOIN subchapters USING (pattern_id)
   JOIN questions USING (chapter_id)
ORDER BY pattern_id, random();
```

That will give one question per pattern. If you want a unique `question_number` use my query as a subquery and generate the number using `row_number() OVER ()`.